# Post data that can be accessed by multiple pages

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to find a way for multiple pages to access the data provided from a single HTML form submission.

Currently, I have 4 pages...

- `index.php` (containing my HTML form)
- `functions.php` (where the HTML
  form sends data to)
- `results1.php`
- `results2.php`

Can anyone please let me know where I'm going wrong or point me in the right direction?

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="functions.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="value1">
    <input type="text" name="value2">
<input type="submit">

</body>
</html>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

$value1 = $_POST["value1"];
$value2 = $_POST["value2"];


?>
```

**results1.php & results2.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<?php include_once("functions.php") ?>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $value1, $value2; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, for starters your HTML has syntax errors and uses the same field name twice

Comment: Ah - it does not in the live version. Errors are just on Stack. Page loads no problem and my issue lies with PHP.

Comment: Please only copy/paste your _actual_ code. Do not try to reproduce by hand, and do not give us something that you think is a "close enough" representation of what you're running.

Comment: _“Can anyone please let me know where I'm going wrong”_ - at the point where you tried to explain what you actually want to achieve here already … Who is calling those two different results script, where and when? Why do they need to be different scripts, what’s the purpose? Depending on that, the answer is either going to be, well do the stuff in one single script then, or store your form data into the _session_, so that the other scripts can access it from there _later on_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using PHP Session.
Try with the given code below.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="functions.php" method="post">
    Value 1: <input type="text" name="value1"><br>
    Value 2 :<input type="text" name="value2"><br>
<input type="submit">

</body>
</html>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["value1"] = $_POST["value1"];
$_SESSION["value2"] = $_POST["value2"];

?>
```

**results1.php & results2.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> 
<?php session_start(); ?>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo 'Value 1:'. $_SESSION["value1"]; ?><br>
<?php echo 'Value 2:'. $_SESSION["value2"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah that seems perfect, but I'm still not getting the data.

Comment: Is the issue maybe something do do with <?php include_once("functions.php") ?

Comment: Oh I removed the above and it works perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear. Thank you too :)

Comment: Just a quick one if you don't mind -  how would you go about the strtoupper with the session variables? I tried echo strtoupper($_SESSION["value1"]); but that didn't work.

Comment: Try with this  $a = $_SESSION["value1"];  echo strtoupper($a);